# sorting a uint64 slice in go

Tags: go, slice

I'm writing Go application using Go 1.7rc3.

I have a slice of `uint64` (`var dirRange []uint64`) that I want to sort.

The sort package has a function `sort.Ints()` but it requires `[]int` and I have `[]uint64`.

What do I do? Can I type cast the all slice?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

As of version 1.8, you can use the simpler function [`sort.Slice`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Slice). In your case, it would be something like the following:

```
sort.Slice(dirRange, func(i, j int) bool { return dirRange[i] < dirRange[j] })
```

This avoids having to define any type just for the sorting.

Comment: I cannot make the edit myself because it is less than 6 characters, but your second argument to Slice, the comparison func needs to declare the index parameters `i` and `j`.

Comment: For the curious: int in golang are platform-dependent and signed (https://golang.org/doc/go1.1#int). Signed 64bit range quite large and isn't a real limit when sorting enormous slices

Comment: I understand this is the correct way to do, but it's kinda annoying to do. I have to define a sorting function for what is a natural comparison of `uint64`. I hope Go comes up with a more natural way to do it in the future.

Answer (score 13):

You can define `sort.Interface` on your `dirRange`, which can be a type aliasing `[]uint64`:

```
type DirRange []uint64

func (a DirRange) Len() int           { return len(a) }
func (a DirRange) Swap(i, j int)      { a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i] }
func (a DirRange) Less(i, j int) bool { return a[i] < a[j] }

func main() {
    dirRange := DirRange{2, 5, 7, 1, 9, 4}
    sort.Sort(dirRange)
    fmt.Println(dirRange)   
}
```

Output:

```
[1 2 4 5 7 9]
```

This way you can avoid casting and work directly with your array. Since the underlying type is a slice `[]uint64`, you can still use general slice operations. For example:

```
dirRange := make(DirRange, 10)
dirRange = append(dirRange, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a type alias for []uint64, add the standard "boilerplate" sorting methods to implement `sort.interface` (`Len`, `Swap`, and `Less` - https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface); then either create an instance of the new type or typecast an existing slice []uint64 into the new type, as done in the following example (also https://play.golang.org/p/BbB3L9TmBI):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type uint64arr []uint64

func (a uint64arr) Len() int           { return len(a) }
func (a uint64arr) Swap(i, j int)      { a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i] }
func (a uint64arr) Less(i, j int) bool { return a[i] < a[j] }
func (a uint64arr) String() (s string) {
    sep := "" // for printing separating commas
    for _, el := range a {
        s += sep
        sep = ", "
        s += fmt.Sprintf("%d", el)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    dirRange := []uint64{3, 2, 400000}
    arr := uint64arr(dirRange)
    sort.Sort(arr)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", arr)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", dirRange)
}
```

The output is:

```
2, 3, 400000
[]uint64{0x2, 0x3, 0x61a80}
```

showing that both arrays are sorted since the second one is a typecasted alias for the original.

Answer (score 0):

There is no wrapper function, you need to use the Slice function, and this is an example:

```
arr := []uint64{5, 0, 3, 2, 1, 6}

sort.Slice(arr, func(i, j int) bool { return arr[i] < arr[j] })
```

Answer (score 0):

This can just be in the above comment

```
sort.Sort(uint64arr(dirRange))
```

dirRange will be sorted no need for arr:=